# Sixteen PCs connected to one monitor?

Tags: vga, splitter

I am looking for a solution, because of space issues, where I can connect 16 PCs to one monitor. Not looking for KVM, I like to monitor 16 Pcs at once.

Basically in our broadcast company, we are looking for a solution where we can connect 16 PCs to a single large size LCD or LED for monitoring purposes.

Comment: What you describe is not possible.  What is possible is using a Remote Desktop client with a single machine even tools to exactly that do some more research on the subject

Comment: A mention of OSes would be critical in answering. You'd also want to talk about how the pcs are linked, and what you're *actually* trying to do.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking more for a broadcast switcher $$$ , especially it being a broadcast company. with one (or2) of those you could view smaller , and even select to pip or full a particular one. Check out the pro video sales location, they would be happy to tell you what they have.  There are consumerish versions of such things for security, sold (again) by the same people.

Answer (score 2):

It will be very small screens if you were to to reduce size of each so you have 4x4 grid (if I understand correctly what you want). And yes, smart enough KVMs would do that (allow you to multiplex several input channels to one output, similar how set top boxes can do for TV signals. You can ignore their "keyboard/mouse" parts of the KVM, of course).

Note however that it would probably cost much more than 16 monitors...

I'm not sure it's allowed to send links to commercial company products, so I'd just recommend to search for "split vga multiplex" or similar phrases.

Mostly you'll find then in 4 channel variants, so you'll need 5 of them (4 to multiplex 4 PCs each, and fifth to multiplex 4 multiplexers).

Answer (score -1):

How much information do you need to get from it? If you only need shell access or text, SSH, telnet, putty, or the compatible equivalent can make headless server maintenance a breeze. Graphical stuff that you'd use remote control desktop requires that you either have 16 mice and keyboards, or the agility and memory to switch from one to the other, which would also let you change monitor wires. And while splitters exist for VGA, you cannot split the display to have "fly vision". I know you can have multiple monitors for one pc, but I don't think that we have the technology for split screen. Depending on your skill leve, you might be able to proxy multiple connections through a computer and then have that act as the most expensive splitter on the face of the earth.

Comment: This seems like a comment since you are asking a question to be provided clarification.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to make a comment. I'm sorry. I'll just garner it somewhere else. But, while I can make comments on my own post, Can reputation gained in other stackexchange sites be used in superuser, or is it site-specific? I know that this probably belongs in superuser meta, but I'm still a complete n00b. Forgive me.

Comment: No;  Reputation is site specific.  You won't get reputation from a comment within an answer.  You should consider just answering the question.  I can't suggest you delete the answer because enough deleted questions with negative reputation WILL cause you to be banned from answering questions.

Comment: If I upvote it to give it exact zero and then delete, am I still banned?

Comment: It takes more then a single bad answer to be answer banned.  It also not a permanent ban provided you address the reason you were banned.  There are many elements into the automatic ban most are not shared to avoid people playing the system. The simplest way to avoid it, don't post comments as answers, since you can't upvote your own answers I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: OK. Didn't know I couldn't upvote my self. I was just asking to hedge my bet.